# Android Studio doesn't remember passwords at "Generate Signed Bundle or APK" anymore (4.1)

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-4.1

This week I built release bundle 3-4 times using Android Studio and I always checked "Remember passwords".

But every time I do a new release build it asks for passwords so "Remember passwords" is ignored, only remembers "key store path" and "key alias" fields.

It was working some time ago but now it doesn't. Mb bug in version 4.1, I don't know.

Does someone have this problem? Can it be solved?

[image]

**Update** it resets passwords for for all project and keeps only for last project which was used for building release bundle/apk

Comment: I wonder if there's an update for this? it is a little inconvenient when you have to manage multiple projects. I've been experiencing this since the 4.1 update as well. Currently in 4.2 too.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: Same problem. I don't even bother to try it anymore it - saw it failing too often.

Comment: I have the same problem on 4.2 +1.

Comment: Still seeing this in 2023!

Comment: @AlRo it's better to use Gradle command to build apps with signing  instead of this ugly tool

Comment: @user25 how? link??